Why is this sentence incorrect: "This is because music has a special way of grabbing our attention and keeping engaging us"?


This is because music has a special way of keeping us engaged.
This is because music has a special way of keeping engaging us.


I'm tutoring a kid in English, and I don't know how to explain to her why the second sentence is incorrect.
I think it obviously sounds weird, but at the same time, the whole construction seems grammatical: keep + Ving (checked); of + Ving (checked).
It can be understood as "Music has a special way to continue engaging us." That doesn't sound so smooth, but I feel like the sentence isn't only incorrect in terms of meaning, but the construction "keeping + Ving" itself also sounds wrong. Maybe it's just me, though. I'd love to hear what you think.

When something catches our attention, it engages us. There is a single moment in time when it engages us.
Keeping relates to a continuous state, not a single moment in time, so you can't say "keeping engaging us".
On the other hand, "engaged" relates to a continuous state, so it is OK to say "keeping us engaged".

Thank you! Do you ever say "keeping + Ving"?

Yes. you can do it when the Ving relates to some continuous activity, for example "keeping going".

The construction is to keep | keeping {object}  {complement}.

This compartment in the fridge is for keeping greens fresh.
Place greens in this compartment to keep them fresh.
Hitchcock's films are famous for keeping audiences engaged.

The complement can be an adjective  or a prepositional phrase that is adjectival in nature.

Hitchcock's films are famous for keeping audiences on the edge of their seats.
Coffee late in the day keeps me up at night.


But we also say: Keep trying and you will succeed. JavaLatte's and your answers are great; I just have one more question: Do we ever use "keeping + Ving"?

When there's a direct object the complement follows the object: Keep me apprised.  or Keep us up-to-date. When there's a participle, the form is the tensed form of keep:  She keeps trying. She kept trying.   But keeping {present participle} is not grammatical.
